# Node.js with express app crashes on Heroku, works locally

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I have a Node.js with express running fine locally but crashes when I try to run it on Heroku.

When I deploy and go to the heroku subdomain:

- The HTML loads but the CSS doesn't
- When I refresh nothing loads and I get the generic application error
- Looking at the logs it seems the app has crashed

Any ideas why heroku keeps crashing? Best guess is something to do with my static files.

Here are the logs:

```
2014-07-19T02:02:00.723361+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed     without response" method=GET path="/javascripts/main.js" host=sendmyemail.herokuapp.com     request_id=3f2d4cd8-c70d-4506-9baf-af8d98983f37 fwd="99.43.254.71" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=43 status=503 bytes=691
2014-07-19T02:02:00.708143+00:00 app[web.1]:         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2014-07-19T02:02:00.709158+00:00 app[web.1]:     at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
2014-07-19T02:02:00.708150+00:00 app[web.1]:               ^
2014-07-19T02:02:00.707641+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-07-19T02:02:00.707753+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:72
2014-07-19T02:02:00.709155+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: spawn ENOENT
2014-07-19T02:02:00.709160+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
2014-07-19T02:02:02.265464+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2014-07-19T02:02:03.554266+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sendmyemail.herokuapp.com request_id=fc319b3f-924f-4e37-bf6f-a58a4dc25770 fwd="99.43.254.71" dyno=web.1 connect=100 service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-19T02:02:02.255985+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.26",
    "npm": "1.4.20"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.2.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "node-compass": "0.2.3",
    "ejs": "~1.0.0",
    "express-ejs-layouts": "~1.1.0",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.5.1"
  }
}
```

I have my css and js in public folder and have this line in app.js:

```
app.use(express['static'](path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: Can you post your repository structure?

Answer (score 10):

I moved the line of code referring to static files (express.static) up above other lines of code and now it works fine on Heroku.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('layout', 'layout'); // defaults to 'layout'
app.use(require('node-compass')({mode: 'expanded'}));
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```