# Heroku Node App Resources Not Loading

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I have an Express Node app that runs fine locally, but when I deploy to Heroku files under `/public` and `/bower_components` are not found.

[image]

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789216/expressjs-not-loading-stylesheets-on-heroku-giving-500-error) seemed to have a similar problem, but the solution did not work for me.

Here is the relevant part of my app.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "postinstall": "bower install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.9.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.8.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
    "consolidate": "~0.10.0",
    "morgan": "~1.3.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.1.3",
    "debug": "~2.0.0",
    "bower": "^1.3.12",
    "dustjs-helpers": "~1.4.0",
    "dustjs-linkedin": "~2.5.0",
    "node-compass": "0.2.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "npm": "2.7.1"
  }
}
```

In the browser console I can verify that all the files are present

[image]

This leads me to believe there is an issue with Heroku reading __dirname correctly.

Comment: I don't know what this could be but I would check 2 things: first, are the relative paths to the files constructed correctly (do they resemble the local paths /app/directory/stuff.js)? second, make sure that the files are actually pushed on heroku: clone the repository in a new location and check integrity. I had a problem once where part of the app would not upload to heroku even though it was not gitignored.

Comment: For your first suggestion: My paths looks like /directory/stuff.js, but __dirname is appended to static files, I have not run into this problem deploying to Heroku before. Second suggestion: In the browser console I can see all the files in the Sources section. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by this post. 
[Node.js with express app crashes on Heroku, works locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836094/node-js-with-express-app-crashes-on-heroku-works-locally/24837921#24837921)

I had to move the following lines above the other app configuration lines in my app.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
```